# Can't submit my facebook app to Live

Tags: facebook

I try to get my Facebook app live, but when I switch the button to live, there's an error occurred.

> You must provide a valid Privacy Policy URL in order take your app
>   Live. Go to App Details and make sure it is valid.

I already put the valid Privacy Policy and Terms of Service URL. But it is still not working.

I've already searched the topic here about the same problem, it is said that it is a bug, but it's from November last year, is it still a bug or there is a solution of this problem now?

Comment: You also need to have a valid (i.e., confirmed) contact email set.

Comment: Actually, I already fill all the fields in Contact Info.

Comment: And the URLs for privacy policy and TOS saved successfully, no error messages there?

Comment: yes, there is no error message when I add the URLs and e-mails

Comment: Go check both URLs using the debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ – if that says it can’t reach those URLs, that might indicate a problem. Otherwise, I’d suggest you go file a bug report for the issue under https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Oh, thank you, when I check it, it is said like below.

Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.

So I assume there might be a problem with the link?